# Declaring variables in for loop using object properties

Tags: javascript, variables, object, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to find a shorter way of declearing variables using the properties of an object.

I have a "userOptions" object passed in as a parameter like this:

```
var example = new myFunction({
    maxLimit: 30,
});
```

In myFunction I have another object called "defaultOptions" which I compare with userOptions to declare the options as variables. Following example may already seem short enough. However it starts to get inefficient when number of options increases.

```
function myFunction(userOptions) {
    var defaultOptions = {
        maxLimit: 20,
        minLimit: 10
    }

    // Apply user options
    for (var i in defaultOptions) {
        if (userOptions.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            defaultOptions[i] = userOptions[i];
        }
    }

    // Declare variables
    var maxLimit = defaultOptions.maxLimit;
    var minLimit = defaultOptions.minLimit;
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322915/iterating-over-variables-in-javascript) is a little bit similar to what I am trying to do. However answers suggest accessing the object properties one by one like I already did.

Is there a better way of doing this task? Like declaring the variables in the for loop or extracting the properties of the updated options object as variables?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to accomplish. If you have this `defaultOptions` object that has the values you want, why not just access them through that object? I.E., wherever you're accessing `maxLimit`, just write `defaultOptions.maxLimit` (you don't need to use the bracket syntax).

Comment: That's what most libraries (e.g. jQuery and jQuery UI) do. Except maybe for some options that are used really frequently for convenience.

Comment: If you don't want to keep typing a long name like `defaultOptions`, you can give it a short name like `var do = defaultOptions;`. Then it's just `do.maxLimit`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are looking for [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), arguments on the right overwrite overlapping properties of objects to the left:

```js
console.log(Object.assign({ id: 1, name: 'Hello' }, { name: 'World' }));
```

Which could be used like:

```
var config = Object.assign(defaultOptions, userSuppliedOptions);
```

---

If instead you are just wanting regular variables and have access to ES6 you could also use [`destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to make things more concise:

```
let { minLimit, maxLimit } = defaultOptions;
```

Comment: His question is about assigning to ordinary variables, not how to merge the objects.

Comment: @Barmar - Thanks for pointing that out, I see what you mean. I still think this could be a better solution than assigning to ordinary variables though so I'm going to leave it for the time being

Comment: What does this do differently from his `for` loop?

Comment: @Barmar I suppose it's speaking to "I am trying to find a shorter way...", though as you pointed out - I am ignoring the 'declare global variables' part.  They could do something silly like: `Object.assign(window, { foo: 'bar' })` though...